# Solving race conditions in Django/postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, race-condition

I have a django view which sends a payment receipt, and in multi-threaded environments, this view sends the receipt multiple times if called more than once in quick succession. My code which does the update looks like

```
updated = Transaction.objects \
    .filter(id=transaction_id, status='processing') \
    .update(status='paid')
if updated:
    # send email
```

Everything I've read on the internet suggests that selecting and updating rows that need to be updated in one query as I've done here should work. What am I doing wrong?

I also tried

```
with transaction.atomic():
    trans = Transaction.objects.select_for_update() \
                       .get(id=transaction_id)
    if trans.status == 'processing':
        trans.status = 'paid'
        trans.save()
        updated = True
    else:
        updated = False
```

Other things I've tried:

- do everything in raw sql, i.e. cursor().execute('...')
- calling transaction.commit() after the update
- setting the Postgres isolation level to SERIALIZABLE

The site runs apache/mod_wsgi, Django 1.8 and Postgres 9.4, and the problem goes away if I set threads=1 processes=1 in my mod_wsgi configuration. I also reproduced the problem with gunicorn, with multiple workers. It's hosted on Webfaction although would assume that doesn't matter.

Comment: Did you try `select_for_update` and `transaction.atomic()` together? I'd expect that to take care of it.

Comment: I did, and no it didn't... I'll add in the code I tried

Comment: `SERIALIZABLE` should definitely prevent these kinds of anomalies. The only explanation I can see is that the select and the save are running in different transactions. I don't know enough about Django to guess where it might be going wrong... All I can suggest is to turn on [statement logging](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-MIN-DURATION-STATEMENT) and see what it's actually sending to the server.